# Export directory as zip with a SaveFileDialog

Tags: node.js, save, node-webkit, nw.js, iojs

I'm using [archiver](https://npmjs.org/package/archiver) to export a directory as a zip file in nodejs/node-webkit.

```
var file_system = require("fs")
var archiver = require("archiver")

var output = file_system.createWriteStream("files.zip")
var archive = archiver("zip")

output.on("close", function() {
  console.log(archive.pointer() + " total bytes")
  console.log("archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.")
})

archive.on("error", function(err) {
  throw err
})

archive.pipe(output)
archive.bulk([
  { expand: true, cwd: "./content/project/", src: ["**"], dest: "./content/project/"}
])
archive.finalize()
```

However I can't find anything on how to have the user set the destination on where the zip file should be exported using a traditional SaveFileDialog.

Does anyone know how I can have the user set the destination on where to export the zip file using a SaveFileDialog in node-webkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to node-webkit's wiki, you can [open a dialog programmatically](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/file-dialogs#how-to-open-a-file-dialog) by simulating a click on a [specially configured html input field](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/file-dialogs#save-file).

So for example you would insert

```html
<input type="file" id="fileDialog" nwsaveas />
<!-- or specify a default filename: -->
<input type="file" id="fileDialog" nwsaveas="myfile.txt" />
```

and use something like this to optionally programmatically trigger the dialog and get the entered path:

```javascript
function chooseFile(name) {
  var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
  chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    console.log(this.value);
  }, false);

  chooser.click();  
}
chooseFile('#fileDialog');
```